# How to find the position of a substring before an position index?

Tags: python, string

I have a string called s:

```
s = "Temperature is 15 degree Celsius. It is expected to be hotter tomorrow, say, 20 degree Celsius."
```

I want to find the word `"degree"` which is nearest to `"tomorrow"` in backward direction.

First, I find the position of `'tomorrow'`, then I search backward from the previously found position to find the word `"degree"`.

The first step is:

```
index = s.index('tomorrow')
```

How to do the second step?

Comment: would make more sense to post an example that has the word `"degree"` at least twice.

Comment: Search in the slice of the substring from 0 to `index` backward with `s.rindex()`.

Comment: So in the corrected example now which `"degree"` position do you want? Is it `3`?

Comment: You could also try to searching using regular expressions! But that would become a bit complicated.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?

```
index = s.index('tomorrow')
index2 = s.rfind('degree', 0, index)
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the position of "tomorrow" as you said, next, you use **rfind** (right find) and you will find the nearest position to "tomorrow".

```
s = "Temperature is 15 degree Celsius. It is expected to be hotter tomorrow, say, 20 degree Celsius."
index = s[0:s.index("tomorrow")].rfind("degree")
```

Answer (score 0):

This recursive generator function produces all the index pairs of two substrings within another string. Then you can use `min` with an appropriate key function to find the one where the indexes are closest:

```
def pairs(s, s1, s2, i=0):
    i1 = s.find(s1, i)   # start looking at index i
    i2 = s.find(s2, i1)  # start looking at index i1
    if i2 < 0 or i1 < 0:  # one wasn't found
        return
    yield i1, i2
    yield from pairs(s, s1, s2, i2)

s = 'xx ab cd xxx ab xx cd'
s1, s2 = 'ab', 'cd'
l = list(pairs(s, s1, s2))
# [(3, 6), (13, 19)]
min(l, key=lambda x: x[1]-x[0])  # indexes of s1, s2 in s where they are closest
# (3, 6)
```